# MongoDB array undefined in Javascript but present in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push an ObjectId into an ObjectId array on another Object, but my array to hold objects comes back as undefined when trying to push to the array, even though it's present the a JSON dump:

[image]

```
 for (let i = 0; i < billedTimeEntries.length; i++) {
    const timeEntry = billedTimeEntries[i];
    const hourLog = await HourLog.find({ _id: timeEntry.hourLog });
    hourLog.timeEntries.push(timeEntry._id);
```

with the .push throwing a 'cannot read property of 'push' of undefined' even though the array is defined in the object supposedly.

My mongoose schema for this ObjectId array looks like this:

```
  timeEntries: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'TimeEntry',
  }],
```

And looks to be defined in the database as an empty array by default.

Comment: have you tried `const hourLog = await HourLog.findOne({ _id: timeEntry.hourLog }).exec();` ?

Comment: That works perfectly, missed that promise implementation.

Comment: ok, posted detailed answer on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HourLog.find` returns `Query`, and [queries are not promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises). Use `Query#exec()` method to get promise out of query and `await` on that promise. Furthermore, since you want to find single HourLog document, you should use `findOne` instead of `find`. This would fix things in your example:

```
const hourLog = await HourLog.findOne({ _id: timeEntry.hourLog }).exec();
```